# Who supports civiCRM in Raleigh NC using Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, cms-integration

Our organization uses civiCRM currently.   We wish to migrate to WordPress for our new website design.   We want three bids for this work.   Who in Raleigh, NC are currently offering such services that are familiar with civiCRM and Wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a good list of available CiviCRM/Wordpress implementation experts here:

https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country=All&services=Implementation&language=All&cms=WordPress

Comment: Good answer, @Eli Lisseck. Patricia Witt, many organizations provide CiviCRM and WordPress services remotely. Tadpole.cc and Christian Wach are leaders in their contributions to making CiviCRM work well with WordPress. Other firms like mine, JMAConsulting.biz, also provide CiviCRM and WordPress services.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, of course, if you can work with a remote consultant please do change the country filter from "US" to "All"! Lots of people doing great stuff out there and it's a common work pattern for software!

Comment: @patricia witt I agree with Eli: we live in a global age thanks to amazing software products and producers all around the world. I'm based in London England and I've done CiviWork for organisations in the Netherlands and the USA.

Comment: exactly. we are in NZ - and that is a long way from NC, but we have two clients there ;-). Smallworld.